# What can be the possible rank of adjoint of matrix of order n?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ A $ be matrix of order $ n $. What may the possible ranks of $\mathop{\rm adj} (A) $? I think the possible answers are $0$, $1$, and $n$.

Comment: That's the right answer. Do you know the characterization of the rank of a matrix in terms of how large a nonsingular submatrix (of square shape) can be?

Comment: If we consider the $n$-square matrix $A_{ij}$ where $a_{ij}=j\;\forall\,1\leq i\leq n$ then $\mathrm{rk}(A)=1$, but since every conjugate $M_{ij}$ has a null determinant (equal columns) $\mathrm{rk}(\mathrm{adj}(A))=0$; as an example.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the explanation. Would you simplify the things?

Comment: I did get some part of the answer. The question is why the rank of adjoint of matrix can't be equal to say 2 (where $ 2\neq n)$